# connection from "spring data solr" to solr in openshift timeout

Tags: spring, solr, openshift

I am facing an issue connecting spring data solr to solr running on openshift.

```
<solr:solr-server id="solrServer"
    url="http://solr-dashapramathi.rhcloud.com/" />

<bean id="solrTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate"
    scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg ref="solrServer" />
</bean>
```

is my configuration. i have also tried the url as "http://solr-dashapramathi.rhcloud.com/#/dashapramathi" I am running Solr 4.10.1 on openshift.

The error is as below:

```
IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr-dashapramathi.rhcloud.com/dashapramathi; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr-dashapramathi.rhcloud.com/dashapramathi
```

Caused by:

org.springframework.data.solr.UncategorizedSolrException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr-dashapramathi.rhcloud.com/dashapramathi; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://solr-dashapramathi.rhcloud.com/dashapramathi
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.execute(SolrTemplate.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:175)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.saveBean(SolrTemplate.java:169)
    at org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository.save(SimpleSolrRepository.java:149)

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to solr-dashapramathi.rhcloud.com:80 timed out
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:129)

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: It works as expected when I am running Solr in my local system.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the documentation listed here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/1.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/solr.repositories.html It looks like it tries to connect through port 8993 which is why would would be receiving the timeout.

OpenShift only allows external connections to be made to 80,8080,443,8443. For inside the gear connections you can alter things to connect to more ports as per the following OpenShift Doc https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202185874.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I've managed to resolve it just by changing the timeout in the definition of the Solr server.
So, for your case it would be:

```
> <solr:solr-server id="solrServer"
>     url="http://solr-dashapramathi.rhcloud.com/" timeout="1000"/>
```

or you can set a higher value for the timeout, depending on your connection.

In the documentation of the Spring Data Solr the 8993 port it is probably the port that the application server which hosts Solr runs on.